# Opening and closing toolbar for design mode

Tags: excel, vba, designmode

I'm trying to get familiar with VBA in Excel.  One of the main things necessary for my first project is creating a UserForm for the end-user to enter the criteria they want to pull data for.

I've gotten a good handle on using the Design Mode toolbox to add text fields, check boxes, etc. to the UserForm when I first generate it:

[image: figure 1]

However, if I have to save and exit from VBA before I've finished adding elements to the UserForm, I can't seem to get that toolbox back when I return:

[image: figure 2]

I've tried toggling off Design Mode from the Run menu before and after opening the UserForm, right-clicking on the form itself to see what my options are... haven't found a consistent solution yet.

Is there any simple way (either through menus or a keyboard shortcut) to "toggle on and off" the Design toolbox shown in the first image linked above?  Regardless of whether it's a pre-existing or brand-new UserForm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toolbox can be found under:

VBA > View > Toolbox

Here:

[image]

Comment: OK, good to know.  I'll be sure to check all the menu drop-downs next time just in case it's in a location I didn't consider.  Thanks!